# Change the styling of the active button in datatables pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatables

I am trying to change the background colour of the active page on the pagination menu for `dataTables`. **Before closing this as a dupe** please note firstly that the example given by an admin in 2020 is seemingly broken: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/177385#Comment_177385 (their editable example is here: https://live.datatables.net/wujasupi/2/edit)

Subsequently, so are these Q&As:

1. [How to change the default hover style of pagination buttons in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837577/how-to-change-the-default-hover-style-of-pagination-buttons-in-datatables) (with answers that do cover the active button)
2. [DataTable pagination page selected color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57408793/datatable-pagination-page-selected-color)

And others I don't care to list since they're all earlier than this apparently-breaking change. When I inspect the button itself, I find the following for the full pagination row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-5"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
        <div class="dataTables_paginate paging_simple_numbers"
             id="suppliersTable_paginate">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="pagination-sm previous disabled" id="suppliersTable_previous">
                    <a aria-controls="suppliersTable"
                       aria-disabled="true"
                       aria-role="link"
                       data-dt-idx="previous"
                       tabindex="0"
                       class="page-link">Previous</a>
                </li>
                <li class="pagination-sm active">
                    <a href="#"
                       aria-controls="suppliersTable"
                       aria-role="link"
                       aria-current="page"
                       data-dt-idx="0"
                       tabindex="0"
                       class="page-link">1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="pagination-sm ">
                    <a href="#"
                       aria-controls="suppliersTable"
                       aria-role="link"
                       data-dt-idx="1"
                       tabindex="0"
                       class="page-link">2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="pagination-sm next" id="suppliersTable_next">
                    <a href="#"
                       aria-controls="suppliersTable"
                       aria-role="link"
                       data-dt-idx="next"
                       tabindex="0"
                       class="page-link">Next</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I admit that my CSS is not very strong and at this point I'm just throwing spaghetti. I just want the current page to be highlighted in a different colour than the standard blue, similar to how it is when you hover over non-disabled buttons. This is my attempt:

```js
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
} );
```

```css
.page-link {
    color: #063970;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6; 
}

.page-link:hover {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #063970 !important;
    border-color: #063970 !important; 
}
/* doesn't work */
.page-link:active {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red !important; 
}
/* doesn't work */
.page-link.current {
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red !important; 
}
/* From https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/77678/pagination-css-problem doesn't work */
.dataTables_paginate .paginate_button.current {
    background: red !important;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6; 
}

/* From the comments below - doesn't work */
.paginate_button.active > .page_link { background-color: #063970; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet"
              href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              rel="stylesheet"
              integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65"
              crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V"
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Position</th>
                        <th>Office</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Start date</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                        <td>System Architect</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2011/04/25</td>
                        <td>$3,120</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                        <td>Director</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>63</td>
                        <td>2011/07/25</td>
                        <td>$5,300</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                        <td>Technical Author</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>66</td>
                        <td>2009/01/12</td>
                        <td>$4,800</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>22</td>
                        <td>2012/03/29</td>
                        <td>$3,600</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
                        <td>Financial Controller</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>33</td>
                        <td>2008/11/28</td>
                        <td>$5,300</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>New York</td>
                        <td>61</td>
                        <td>2012/12/02</td>
                        <td>$4,525</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                        <td>San Francisco</td>
                        <td>59</td>
                        <td>2012/08/06</td>
                        <td>$4,080</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>55</td>
                        <td>2010/10/14</td>
                        <td>$6,730</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>55</td>
                        <td>2010/10/14</td>
                        <td>$6,730</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>55</td>
                        <td>2010/10/14</td>
                        <td>$6,730</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>55</td>
                        <td>2010/10/14</td>
                        <td>$6,730</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                        <td>Edinburgh</td>
                        <td>55</td>
                        <td>2010/10/14</td>
                        <td>$6,730</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Specific versions:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
```

Browser: Version 120.0.6099.216 (Official Build) (arm64)

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan you can use the one from the `dataTables` admin: https://live.datatables.net/wujasupi/2/edit

Comment: @roganjosh there's also a starter "kit" in the [SO datatables wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datatables/info) - the onus is on *you* to provide this, not for us to [edit] your question for you!

Comment: @freedomn-m ok, I apologise for not noticing that. I clearly wasn't asking you to edit my question for me; I'm not familiar with this tag. I will work to update the question but I obviously can't do that instantly

Comment: No worries - using the sample link provided (https://live.datatables.net/wujasupi/854/edit) and inspecting the button, shows the css selector should be: `.dt-paging .dt-paging-button.current {`  Looks like all the classes are being changed for 2.0 release which that link uses (nightly)

Comment: That doesn't work for me locally. I will work on building an example but it will take me a bit

Comment: That's because you're using 1.13.4 not 2.0.0 - I was looking at the link you provided.  Hence the need for [mcve] 

Comment: Also looks like you're adding bootstrap5, which will probably change all the classes

Comment: @freedomn-m I think I have given the example asked for

Comment: `.paginate_button.active > .page_link { background-color: blue; }` will set the background-color - *but* it appears to conflicting with your custom styles (`!important` maybe) - remove those and that line works.

Comment: @freedomn-m indeed, that does work for my example. I haven't got a clue what custom style it's clashing with on my site because I have done minimal styling for datatables outside of what is shown, but that is definitely worth an answer and I will be happy to accept since this isn't documented anywhere I could find for this version. It's got me a lot further on, thank you

Comment: @freedomn-m that's a red-herring. The default colour is blue but if you change it to red, it still hasn't updated the active page colour. Removing `!important` from the other styling options also stops them from working properly too

Comment: My bad, typo due to the dodgy mixture of `-` and `_` in the DT classes:  it should be `.paginate_button.active > .page-link {`   https://jsfiddle.net/f73m5q6r/

Comment: @freedomn-m amazing, thank you! From your correction there I have been able to link it to the "inspect" element too, so now it makes sense. I managed to adapt to to small buttons too, which become `.pagination-sm.active`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@freedomn-m answered this in the comments so I'm just writing up their solution.

The eventual solution was:

```
.paginate_button.active > .page-link {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Armed with this as a basis, I could tackle a slight complication; I actually use smaller button styles with:

```
<script>
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.classes.sPageButton = 'pagination-sm';
</script>
```

In, which case, the solution is modified as such:

```
.pagination-sm.active > .page-link {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Put together:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

```css
.page-link {
  color: #063970;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
}

.page-link:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-color: #063970 !important;
  border-color: #063970 !important;
}

.paginate_button.active > .page-link {
    background-color: red !important;
    border-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-pvPw+upLPUjgMXY0G+8O0xUf+/Im1MZjXxxgOcBQBXU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>DataTables - JS Bin</title>


        <div class="container">
          <table id="example" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
              <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
              </tr>
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$3,120</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$5,300</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$4,800</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$3,600</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Jenna Elliott</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$5,300</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$4,525</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$4,080</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$6,730</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$6,730</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$6,730</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$6,730</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$6,730</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
```